# I'm writing a code to detect if there is a character repeated in the string but whenever I try to run it, I get a run-time error

Tags: java, exception, runtime-error

The code looks like this:

public static void main(String[] args)
    {

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String name = sc.next().trim();

    for(int count=1; count<=name.length(); count++)
    {

        char ch = name.charAt(count);

        for(int down = name.length(); down>0; down--) {

            char sh;
            sh = name.charAt(down);

            if(ch == sh)
            {
                System.out.println("There is a repeated word");
            }else{
                System.out.println("There is no repeated word");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The error says this:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at numstuff.main(numstuff.java:23)

Comment: Both your loops use ranges `1 .. length`, but Java does most indexes starting at 0, not 1, aka [**0-based**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering), so ranges should be `0 .. (length-1)`. The **documentation** says this explicitly, i.e. javadoc of [`charAt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-) says: *Returns the `char` value at the specified index. An index ranges from `0` to `length() - 1`. The first `char` value of the sequence is at index `0`, the next at index `1`, and so on, as for array indexing*.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses 0-indexing.  `name[2]` refers to the third character in `name`.  `name.length` isn't a valid index in name.  Use `name.length - 1` instead.